# How to retain values from textarea after submitting the form

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a textarea and then I try to click Save as draft button or submit button. But when the page submits, the values on my textarea doesn't retain.

```
<textarea type="text" name="briefDescription" id="briefDescription" rows="12" cols="98" value="${briefDescription}" ></textarea>
```

Please teach me how to retain values of a textarea.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The content of the textarea should go between its start and end tag:

```
<textarea type="text" name="briefDescription" id="briefDescription" rows="12" cols="98">$briefDescription</textarea>
```